# Alert dialog in Fragment, app get crashed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I want to display the alert dialog when onClick of the button in fragment layout. I have tried but the app is crashing when it runs.

```
 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    binding = FragmentWalletBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

    Button button = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.add_money);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
            alertdialog.setMessage("this is message");
            alertdialog.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"toast message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).show();
        }
    });

    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

[image: log message]

Comment: what's the point of doing findViewById and ViewBinding ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onCreateView` returns `View` which can be further obtained by `getView()` method. and you are calling it before `onCreateView` had a chance to return own `View` for framework (its still inside method, didn't `return binding.getRoot();` yet)

if you are using view binding then obtain your `Button` from there

```
Button button = (Button) binding.addMoney;
```

or even just use strictly (without additional local `Button`)

```
binding.addMoney.setOnClickListener(...
```

and if you REALLY WANT to use `findViewById` (but why...), then you can look inside `binding.getRoot()` even when it isn't returned/drawn yet

```
Button button = (Button) binding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.add_money);
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I made it conflict, thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem in

```
(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.add_money);
```

please make sure id is same as in XML.